# First Client-Side Websocket Emit Very Slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have an angular/mysql/express/node app and am using socket.io.

The page loads at normal speed, but after angular is bootstrapped and the first socket.io `emit` is sent, the response takes very long.  Additionally, as the server persists, the response time increases.

I've found that the time from when Angular emits a socket message to the server receiving the message is where the slowdown is happening.  Sockets connect on client-side almost immediately, but the first message takes a very long time to send.  All subsequent emits are normal speed.

This slowdown is present in all browsers.

Any help is very appreciated.  Thanks!